# Is there a way to disable power management on a Seagate ST2000DM001 harddrive completely?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, power-management, spinup

After I bring my Seagate ST2000DM001 harddrive offline using Diskpart, then spin it down using HDDScan for Windows 3.3, and then finally disable its device driver using DevCon so that AFAIK no software nor the Windows OS can cause it to spin up again, after some minutes it spins up anyhow.

However, as soon as that happens, it immediately spins down again. After that, it doesn't spin up anymore until I re-enable its device driver using either DevCon or Device Manager.

Is there any way to teach the disk not to spin itself up again?